# why SSIS File System Task is not moving the file where I want it

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, expression, etl

I am trying to archive a file.  included in the image is the settings of my system file task.  I'm trying to send a file whose name is stored in a variable within the loop, and send that file into the requisite folder.

[image]

The file is supposed to land in `F:\DATA\ARCHIVE\WELLBORE\` using the filename it was given.  However, it keeps landing in `F:\DATA\ARCHIVE` with the NAME `WELLBORE`, which is not what I am looking for.

What do I have missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

The issue is when you select `Move File` so you have to select the source full file path and the destination full file path, so the destination variable should contains the destination full path (with file name) and if the variable contains a folder path, the folder name will be considered as a filename and it will throw an exception.

## Solution

Create a new variable `@[User::DestinationFile]` and assign the following expression to it:

```
@[User::ArchiveFolder] + RIGHT( @[User::WellBoreFile] , FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::WellBoreFile] ) , "\\", 1) - 1)
```

This expression will add the filename to the destination path. And use this new variable as a Destination

---

**References**

- [SSIS EXPRESSION TO GET FILE NAME FROM FULL PATH](https://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/ssis-expression-to-get-file-name-from-full-path/)
- [SSIS Expression to get filename from FilePath](https://sandeepdhanush.wordpress.com/2012/12/27/ssis-expression-to-get-filename-from-filepath/)
- [Microsoft Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/file-system-task)*

Comment: Hi Hadi...thanks for the answer, but what I have is `@[Project::SourceFolder] + "\\WELLBORE\\"` as the expression.  Does that change things?  I have several jobs that reflect different subfolders of a master source folder.  in this job, it's it's a WELLBORE subfolder.

Comment: @arcee123 ah i miss that the Scop is different. i removed this note from my answer. Did changing operation Type fixed your issue?

Comment: no.  it error out because the folder exist with older documents.  also, just FYI: the SourceFolder variable is the actual folder/file location of the file.

Comment: @arcee123 in the foreach loop what is the variable that you mapped the files path to it

Comment: @User:WellBoreFile is the variable with the filename for each iteration of the loop

Comment: There it is.  Thank you so much!